# Howto determine the Oracle client version number using VBA?

Tags: oracle, vba, client, version

Does anyone know how to get the currently used Oracle client version number using VBA?
(And the info "32bit" or "64bit" Client.)

If so, could you please post example code?

Thanks much in advance.

1) the connection to Oracle is OK

2) connection via ADO and the MS Driver

3) the connection object properties are showing a lot of information abaout the driver, the connection and the database. But no info about the oracle client:

- Asynchable Abort: FALSE
- Asynchable Commit:    FALSE
- Pass By Ref Accessors:    TRUE
- Catalog Location: 2
- Catalog Term: Datenbankverknüpfung
- Catalog Usage:    1
- Column Definition:    1
- NULL Concatenation Behavior:  2
- Connection Statu:s    1
- Data Source Name: BASE
- Read-Only Data Source:    FALSE
- DBMS Name:    Oracle
- DBMS Version: 09.02.0000 Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production
- Data Source Object Threading Model:   1
- GROUP BY Support: 4
- Heterogeneous Table Support:  1
- Identifier Case Sensitivity:  1
- Maximum Index Size:   0
- Maximum Open Chapters:    0
- Maximum Row Size: 0
- Maximum Row Size Includes BLOB:   TRUE
- Maximum Tables in SELECT: 0
- Multiple Parameter Sets:  TRUE
- Multiple Results: 0
- Multiple Storage Objects: FALSE
- Multi-Table Update:   FALSE
- NULL Collation Order: 2
- OLE Object Support:   1
- ORDER BY Columns in Select List:  FALSE
- Output Parameter Availability:    2
- Persistent ID Type:   4
- Prepare Abort Behavior:   2
- Prepare Commit Behavior:  2
- Procedure Term:   PL/SQL - Gespeicherte Prozedur
- Provider Friendly Name:   Microsoft OLE DB Provider für Oracle
- Provider Name:    MSDAORA.DLL
- OLE DB Version:   2
- Provider Version: 02.81.1132.0
- Quoted Identifier Sensitivity:    4
- Rowset Conversions on Command:    TRUE
- Schema Term:  Besitzer
- Schema Usage: 15
- SQL Support:  267
- Structured Storage:   1
- Subquery Support: 31
- Transaction DDL:  2
- Isolation Levels: 1052672
- Isolation Retention:  0
- Table Term:   Tabelle
- User Name:    REPORT
- Table Statistics Support: 3
- Open Rowset Support:  8
- Password:     b_rep
- User ID:      report
- Data Source:      BASE
- Window Handle:
- Locale Identifier:    1031
- OLE DB Services:  -7
- Prompt:       4
- Extended Properties:
- Autocommit Isolation Levels:  4096

Comment: too lazy to research?

Comment: I couldn't find any solution using VBA code to do this task. But I interpret your answer this way: You found the code. So please let me know!

Comment: are you OK connecting to the oracle? how are you doing it? have you looked at your connection object properties?

Comment: Please don't dump loads of information into comments; it is hard to read and could be deleted at any time. Edit the question and add it to that, preferably formatted to be readable.

Comment: Thx. I moved the content of my comment to my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible in VBA but in VB.NET you can do it like this:

```
Dim con As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim architecture As String

architecture = System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(con.GetType.Assembly.Location).ProcessorArchitecture.ToString

Console.WriteLine("Architecture: " & architecture)
Console.WriteLine("Assembly: " & con.GetType.Assembly.FullName)
```